# mac magic mouse horizontal swipe/scroll issue in firefox 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webkit

I have added `overflow-x: hidden` to my css html tag in order to hide the slides that are floated to the left, each slide fills the whole window. These slides are then accessed using a navigation, this works fine in all browsers hiding the horizontal scroll as it should.

I have come across a problem now though where even though the horizontal scrollbar is hidden the hidden pages can be scrolled to using the magic pad swipe/scroll.

Is there anyway this can be disabled using a specific webkit css property or by adding javascript?

I have seen posts where people have instructed users to disable the swipe/scroll in through terminal etc but that's not what Im after.

I have found this problem only to happen in Firefox 6 for mac so far.

Thanks
Kyle

Answer (score 1):

If the overflow property isn't working, try using `JQuery.scrollTop()` or `JQuery.scrollLeft()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#element").scroll(function(){
        $(this).scrollTop(0);
        $(this).scrollLeft(0);
    });
});
```

That's the only thing that comes to mind, to be honest.
I assume of course that the swipe/scroll triggers a scroll event, otherwise that function would fail, in which case I know of no working solution.

Comment: is it possible to completely disable the horizontal scroll in firefox using something like this:  document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      e.cancelBubble = false;
      return false;
  }, false);

Comment: I am unsure whether or not the swipe/scroll will trigger that event. If it does, it is a viable solution.

Comment: My own recent experience (which led me to this question) suggests, that the Mac horizontal scroll thing doesn't fire a scroll event in jQuery.